# Edit application shortcuts in "Open With" context menu

Tags: 14.04, gnome, context-menu

I want to edit the application shortcuts that appear on gnome3 context-menu when I right click over a file. For all my text files, I have a certain application that appears under "Open with" and I want to open it with some custom arguments.

I want to edit the "Open With"->Application, I do not want to add another.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but i do not want to delete it the Application, I want to edit the custom exec command.

Comment: You can **delete** the association and then **add** the custom one.